# Multiple definitions of - GCC bogus error

Tags: c, gcc, avr, avr-gcc

I have a header file `lcd.h` with this (shortened):

```
#pragma once
// ...
const uint8_t LCD_ROW_ADDR[] = {0x00, 0x40, 0x14, 0x54};
// ... other prototypes and macros...
```

And a file `lcd.c` where this variable is used:

```
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdint.h>
// ...

#include "lcd.h"

// ...

/** Set cursor position */
void lcd_xy(const uint8_t x, const uint8_t y)
{
    lcd_set_addr(LCD_ROW_ADDR[y] + (x));
}
```

I include  `lcd.h` in `main.c`, and `lcd.c` is compiled separately using makefile.

I'm getting this error: "multiple definition of `LCD_ROW_ADDR'"

```
avr-gcc -std=gnu99 -mmcu=atmega328p -DF_CPU=16000000UL -I. -Ilib/ -funsigned-char -funsigned-bitfields -fpack-struct -fshort-enums -Wall -Wno-main -Wno-strict-prototypes -Wno-comment -g2 -Wextra -Wfatal-errors -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -Wl,--gc-sections -Wl,--relax -DDEBO_CHANNELS=6 -DDEBO_TICKS=1 -Os main.c lib/debounce.c lib/lcd.c lib/adc.c  --output main.elf
/tmp/ccgfa1iK.o: In function `lcd_xy':
/home/ondra/git/avr-projects/devel/lcdsnake/lib/lcd.c:203: multiple definition of `LCD_ROW_ADDR'
/tmp/cc0iT39O.o:/home/ondra/git/avr-projects/devel/lcdsnake/main.c:424: first defined here
/usr/bin/avr-ld: Disabling relaxation: it will not work with multiple definitions
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:87: recipe for target 'main.elf' failed
make: *** [main.elf] Error 1
```

I have checked the files multiple times and there is no other definition of the variable. The "first defined here" is a lie, the line in `main.c` contains an infinite loop code, nothing related to this.

What's going on here?

(ps. If I move the variable into the `lcd.c` file, it compiles OK - but I want to have it in the header file, so it can be accessed from elsewhere, too)

Comment: Does it pop up more than once if you make `gcc` output its preprocessed file?

Comment: Mind elaborating on your remark, @Blindy? I believe I know pretty well what const means, how is it relevant here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

ld is correct. You have the same variable defined in two separate compilation units thanks to the header.

The way to fix this is to declare it `extern` in the header, and have only *one* of the units redeclare it without the `extern` qualifier in its .c file.

Comment: But I have it declared only once, in the header file

Comment: Which is then included in two separate compilation units. The compiler and linker don't actually care where it shows up, only that it shows up in more than one compilation unit.

Comment: `#pragma once` only prevents the header from being included multiple times into the same compilation unit.

Comment: Of course it works, he's talking about different compilation units.

Comment: Sorry, I don't follow. In preprocessor listing, the line is only once.

Comment: It's once in the preprocessor listing for each unit. If you preprocess `lcd.c` it's in there, and it's also in `main.c` if you preprocess that.

Comment: Oh, the header file is included twice in two "c" files, now I get it.