# atmel studio ifndef compilation error

Tags: arduino, code-cleanup, atmel, atmelstudio

Hi imy project recognises double definitions of variables that do not exist 2 times. I suppose that some how by changing my code and recompiling it stucks.

> LedMatrix7219.cpp.o:(.data.Alphaletter+0x0): multiple definition of `Alphaletter' LedController.cpp.o:(.data.Alphaletter+0x0): first
>   defined here
>
> LedMatrix7219.cpp.o:In function `loop'
>   LedController.cpp.o:(.bss.arr+0x0): first defined here
>
> LedMatrix7219.cpp.o:In function `loop'
>   LedController.cpp.o:(.data.Alphaletter2+0x0): first defined here
>
> collect2.exe*:error: ld returned 1 exit status

I have a class LedController and a header LettersDefinition.h

All the headers start like this:

I am including a struct and an enum from the LetterDefinition.h to the LedController so at the header i need to include the LetterDefinition.h in order to make a certain struck.

```
#ifndef __LEDCONTROLLER_H__
#define __LEDCONTROLLER_H__

#include <Arduino.h>
#include "LettersDefinition.h"

LetterStruct finalText;
String theText="Test";

void test();
//it does some extra staff
#endif //__LEDCONTROLLER_H__
```

And the header of the letter definition.

```
#ifndef LETTERSDEFINITION_H_
#define LETTERSDEFINITION_H_

#include "arduino.h"
#include <avr/pgmspace.h>

struct LetterStruct{

    lettersEnum name;
    uint8_t size;
    uint8_t columnSize[5];
    uint8_t data[18];
}Alphaletter;
#endif /* LETTERSDEFINITION_H_ */
```

And from my main .ide file i call the test function of the Ledcontroller i a get the error you see above. The test fuction just checks the LetterStruct.name variable nothing more.

My .ide is something like:

```
#include <SPI.h>
#include <Adafruit_GFX.h>
#include <Max72xxPanel.h>
#include "LedController.h"   

LedController controller;

void setup()
{
    //irrelevant inits
}

void loop()
{
    controller.test();
    delay(2000);
}
```

If i delete the #include "LettersDefinition.h" from the LedController.h this error gives its place to an error that the LetterStruct is not defined in the LedController.h which is normal since i have to add the LettersDefinition.h in order to be defined.

Comment: Are you sure you didn't mean to define that as a type?

Comment: as u see i just declare a certain struck of type letterstruct this is all that i do.The struck is defined at the letterDefinition.h

Comment: And then you declare a variable of that type called "Alphaletter".

Comment: i declare and then i initiate the alphaletter and in the test function i try to check the variable alphaletter.name

Comment: Yes, and you declare it in two different compilation units.

Comment: why do you say that.if i type int favNumber=5 in one header and then go to another header , include the first one and che if(favNumber==10){//and do something} why do i declare it twice

Comment: Headers are not compilation units.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75603/discussion-between-kyrpav-and-ignacio-vazquez-abrams).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Multiple definitions of - GCC bogus error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29189045/multiple-definitions-of-gcc-bogus-error)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem originates that you "define" variables in header files.  This in general will lead to the multiple definition problem and is not standard design.

The model you need to follow is to define once in a source file:

```
//some.cpp
// this is define
int variableX = 5;
```

And declare in the header file:

```
//some.h
// this is declare
extern int variableX;
```

Every other source file that includes the header just processes the "extern" line, which says roughly "there is an int variableX that will exist in the final program".  The compiler runs over every .cpp .c file and creates a module.  For the some.cpp that defines the variable, it will create the variableX.  All the other .cpp files will just have the extern reference which is a placeholder.  The linker will resolve those placeholders when it combines all the modules together.

In your specific case, this means changing:

```
// .h file should only be externs:
extern LetterStruct finalText;
extern String theText;

// .cpp file contains definitions
LetterStruct finalText;
String theText="Test";
```

Comment: since i want to use the finalText inside the class and the thetext variable also i suppose there is no problem with them. cause this way every variable of every class should have been extern in order to get defined at the cpp and not have a problem

Comment: Class member variables do not use extern.